# Send Byte from jComboBox

Tags: java, byte, jcombobox

I have a jComboBox with these values:

```
String[] preset = { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5" };
```

So if "1" is selected then i want to add a byte to my OutputStream.

```
byte preset1 = 0X01;
```

based on the selection in the combobox. I thought it might be this but it gives a NullPointerException.

```
byte preset = (byte)setPresetcomboBox.getSelectedItem();
            try {

                byte[] command = {(byte) startTx, address, setPreset, 0x00, preset, endTx, 0x0F};               
                TwoWaySerialComm.SerialWriter sw = new TwoWaySerialComm.SerialWriter(
                        twoWaySerCom.serialPort.getOutputStream());

            sw.out.write(command);

            } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

What am i doing wrong here? Apologies if this is obvious, this is my first ever project.

Answer (score 0):

This was solved by changing

```
String[] preset = { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5" };
```

to

```
Byte[] preset = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
```

making the combobox like this:

```
setPresetcomboBox = new JComboBox<Byte>(preset);
```

and my action performed:

```
byte _preset = (Byte)setPresetcomboBox.getSelectedItem();
```